# MacBook Pro not using full physical space of external monitor via HDMI cable

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I have the latest 2019 13 inch MacBook Pro.  When I connect it to my external monitor (LG Flatron E2251) with an HDMI cable, there is a gap at the edge of the monitor all the way round.  It doesn't use the full physical space of the screen, see image below:
    [image]

The resolution of the monitor is 1920x1080 and I'm already displaying at that resolution.  This didn't happen with an old MacBook Pro which I connected with a VGA / DVI adapter.

Comment: A lot of those old monitors used to have some kind of 'fit to screen' option buried in the OSD. Many worked more like CRT TVs than modern monitors. Manual is at https://www.lg.com/uk/support/support-product/lg-E2251VR-BN

Comment: In System Preferences > Display Preferences, if you check "Scaled", see what options are offered.

Comment: @tetsujin the option to fit to screen gets disabled if u attach an HDMI cable. It actually says that in the manual u linked. Guess I'm out of luck